# LibreOffice Calc: check if cell is a formula

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to implement some conditional formatting in LibreOffice Calc (v5.4.4.2 but can upgrade) that will highlight cells whose values are calculated through a formula rather than entered directly.

For example, a cell containing

```
=A3
```

will be highlighted, while

```
Hello world!
```

in cell A3 will not be.

I understand conditional formatting, etc; I just need to determine the correct formulae for checking if a cell actually contains a formula.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a simple solution without conditional formatting, enable "[Value Highlighting" (CTRL+F8)](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Value_Highlighting). This will modify the font color automatically:

- formula results appear in green,
- numerical values in blue,
- text in black.

If you need custom formatting (e.g. setting the cell background, or restrict the formatting to formula results), just use the [ISFORMULA()](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#ISFORMULA) function. To create a conditional formatting rule for range B3:D5, just define a conditional formatting rule with Formula set to `ISFORMULA(B3)` - LO will apply it to the complete range, adapting the parameter automatically.